# USB device is not authorized for usage when connecting the device

Tags: 20.04, usb, devices

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running on a Dell-XPS-15.
When I restart my computer, my USB devices are detected and everything is fine. Then if I unplug the device and plug it in again - it is not recognized anymore until next restart.
When I connect the device with dmesg -w I get the following:

```
[ 2597.029465] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 2597.184660] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2817, bcdDevice= 3.a3
[ 2597.184665] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2597.184667] usb 1-3: Product: USB2.0 Hub             
[ 2597.184668] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[ 2597.184822] usb 1-3: Device is not authorized for usage
[ 2598.065839] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 13
```

and the device is not shown in lsusb.
I dont have usbgurad and I tried basically everything I could find online but with no success. Will appreciate any help, thank you!